# Updating custom CSS properties through Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using paper-scroll-header-panel and using the custom CSS property

```
 paper-scroll-header-panel {
   --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
            background-image: url(images/abcd.jpg);
          };
}
```

to style the full sized header. My problem is that the header image of this custom component should vary based on the image url passed from the page that loads this component. As such, I have defined a property and tried to assign it through a computed property, but this does not seem to work. This is what I have done.

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel style$={{backgroundCover}}>
```

and in the JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'dummy-layout',
  properties: {
    cover: String,
    backgroundCover: {
        type: String,
        computed: 'computeBackground(cover)'
    }
  },    
  computeBackground: function(cover) {
    return '--paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: { background-image: url(' + cover + ');};';
    },
```

### But this does not work. How can I use a background-image that varies for different component instances while using a custom CSS component?

Update: The current code is as below. Still not working.

```
<dom-module id="recipe-layout">

  <link rel="import" type="css" href="recipe-layout.css">
  <style is="custom-style">

    paper-scroll-header-panel {
      position: absolute;
      /* background for toolbar when it is at its full size */
      --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
        background-image: url();
      };
      /* background for toolbar when it is condensed */
      --paper-scroll-header-panel-condensed-header: {
        background-color: #00bcd4;
      };
    }
    paper-toolbar {
      height: 400px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
<template>
 <paper-scroll-header-panel condenses condensed-header-height="56" id="scroller">

        <!-- Main Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"></paper-icon-button>
          <div class="flex"></div>
          <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
          <div class="bottom title"><content select=".cover-title"></content></div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <div class="content">
            <content select=".main-content"></content>
        </div>

      </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'dummy-layout',

      properties: {
        cover: {
            type: String,
            observer: '_updateBg'
        },
      },

      _updateBg: function(cover) {
        this.async(function() { this.subupdateBg(cover); }, 100);
      },

      subupdateBg: function(cover) {
        var scrollerBg = this.$.scroller;
        console.dir(scrollerBg);
        var newStyle = 'background-image: url('+ cover + ');';
        scrollerBg.customStyle['--paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header'] = newStyle;
        scrollerBg.updateStyles();
    }
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change custom css properties in the style attribute since it is only evaluated at the element's creation time. You'll have to apply them inside the customStyle property inside the element and then call the updateStyles method.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api

Answer (score 1):

@Neil is right. This `--paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header` is kind of CSS variable. [Here I made a small example](http://plnkr.co/edit/enlpUomD3lUf99YigmkM), where I demonstrate how to manipulate them:

```
<dom-module id="dummy-layout">

  <style>
    :host {
      --bg: {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }

    .test {
      @apply(--bg);
    }
  }
  </style>

    <template>
      <div class="test">Hello world</div>
      <button type="button" on-click=btn>Click</button>
    </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "dummy-layout",
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_updateStyle'
        },
      },
      btn: function () {
        this.set('data', Math.random());
      },
      _updateStyle: function () {
        var colors = ['blue', 'green'];
        this.i = (this.i || 0) + 1;
        var newStyle = 'background-color: '+colors[this.i%2]+';';
        this.customStyle['--bg'] = newStyle;
        this.updateStyles();
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Your code almost works. What actually happens is that your style changing code is never called, because cover is never changed. If you add button that changes it or anything else it works. Here is your code with little modifications: http://pastebin.com/beNAYMRF

Comment: I did - 

<style is="custom-style">
    paper-scroll-header-panel {
      --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
        background-image: url();
      };
</style>

And in the JS:

properties: {
  cover: {
   type: String,
   observer: '_updateBg'
  },
},
   _updateBg: function(cover) {
  this.async(function() { this.subupdateBg(cover); }, 100);
   },
   
   subupdateBg: function(cover) {
  var scrBg = this.$.scroller;
  var newStyle = 'background-image: url('+ cover + ');';
  scrBg.customStyle['--paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header'] = newStyle;
  scrBg.updateStyles();
 },

Didnt work.

Comment: Please see the original post. I have updated it with the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the source for paper-scroll-header-panel(https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-scroll-header-panel/blob/master/paper-scroll-header-panel.html), you will see that the style values you enter in '--paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header' get applied to #headerBg (line 127).

So, you could simply change the background image by changing headerBg's style. If you're using the Polymer Starter Kit, you can add this line in your app.js:

```
    document.querySelector('paper-scroll-header-panel').$.headerBg.style.backgroundImage = "url(path/to/image)";
```

Or in your case:

```
    this.$.scroller.$.headerBg.style.backgroundImage = "url(path/to/image)";
```

Plunker Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/gd6S7q?p=preview